# What will the reaction forces of a support be in case of an angled cable

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, structures, mechanical

If a cable is attached to a support on each side, and there is a load acting on it somewhere along its length.

Is there going to be a vertical reaction force only if the the cable is angled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The reaction force is a vector in the direction (or opposite) of the cable.

Note that the only way to have a horizontal cable is by having the other support higher.  But if you do, a horizontal vector will resolve into only a horizontal force.  The sin of 0 is zero, so an angle of zero will yield zero vertical force.

Comment: Say there is a simple support attached to the horizontal part, and the horizontal part experiences a load Fh due to something hanging from it, while still remaining horizontal. That would mean there is only a horizontal force, but what about the simple support? It will have a horizontal reaction force equal in size to the horizontal load exerted on the horizontal cable, but will there also be vertical reaction forces from the simple support?

Comment: All forces will resolve back to the support, wherever it attaches.  But I don't understand how something hangs with a horizontal force.  Gravity is vertical.  A horizontal cable will not pass any vertical load.  A cable strung from equal supports must have some droop.  Any cable with a weight strung from it in this way will have a deflection unless you can apply infinite tension.